# I want to put two columns side by side using floats, but one column is not placed properly...why?

Tags: html, css

My aside element is positioned at the bottom...it should be on top, at the same level as my section...what I'm doing wrong??? I want these two columns to be at the same level, so I used floats in both, section and aside, but obviusly is not working...please help!

And also I can't

My HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Layout with Floats</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
```

```
<body>

  <header>
    <h1>Leonardo da Vinci</h1>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Inicio</a></li>
        <li><a>Bio</a></li>
        <li><a>Obras</a></li>
        <li><a>Legado</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section>
    <div class="columnas">

    </div>
    <div class="columnas">

    </div>
    <div class="columnas">

    </div>
    <div class="columnas">

    </div>
  </section>

  <aside>
    <div>

    </div>
  </aside>

</body>
</html>
```

My CSS code:

```
header {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 55px 0 0 0;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

header ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

header ul li {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
}

section {
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden
  float: left;
}

section .columnas {
  background: red;
  width: 280px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 15px 15px 0 0;
  float: left;
}

aside {
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}

aside div {
  background: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it properly, and if this is the [solution](https://codepen.io/abidishajia/pen/mpZbzj) you want, you were just missing a semi-colon after hidden.

```
section {
  width: 45%;
  overflow: hidden
  float: left;
 }
```

You can add margin-top: 15px to aside to get it at the exact level.

```
aside {
 width: 30%;
 float: right;
 margin-top: 15px;
 }
```

Comment: How do I mark your answer as THE answer? Sorry, I'm new :(

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.

Comment: I tried <aside> using @abidishajia 's answer for my project and it is working without any problem.